# LED lamp is flicking. How to troubleshot?

Tags: led, bulb

I have [this led floor lamp](https://www.brilliant-ag.eu/en/indoor-lighting/floor-lamps/uplighter/7374/ollie-led-floor-uplight-reading-arm-iron/white) and the upright light/bulb has started to flicker yesterday. The lamp has been already  a little bit problematic because recently the [LED driver](https://www.brilliant-ag.eu/en/spares/transformers-drivers/3416/spare-part-plug-in-power-supply-led-transformer-sunniva-demian-black) broke and I have to order one to the manufacturer, which was a pain in the…

I'm guessing that the problem now it's the led bulb, but has started to go bad for some reason I don't know. This is an educated guess since the other light/bulb is working just fine, in consequence only can be either the bulb or the dimmer.

Is there any way I can asses what is the faulty part using a multimeter, for example?

Comment: I would (carefully) check the supply voltage and make sure it’s 230v, for which this lamp is rated. The internal LED voltage converter will sometimes behave weirdly if powered by below spec voltage.

Comment: do you mean the driver? the lamp has the led driver outside the lamp (please check the link above). I'm adamant to think it's the cause because the manufacturer sent me like two months ago, But it doesn't look really sturdy, so could be.

Comment: I'm thinking to check the output current and see if it's constant. Any idea of what exactly have to check on the output of the driver?

Comment: It's not a **driver** *per se*, in that it doesn't drive a constant current.  It is a constant-voltage **power supply** at 33 volts DC. Max current is 0.8 amps, with both lights on the lamp pulls around 0.75A.   If it were a driver, the voltage would be variable and the amps would be precise.  Also the power supply is happy on 100-240V input, which is typical of switching power supplies.  So significant undervoltage in a 230V world is not a cause for concern.

Comment: that wall wort is very very cheap and unreliable. get a real one from someplace else.

Comment: @dandavis what do you mean with wall wort? do you mean the power supply / driver or whatever you all consider it is.

Comment: the power supply is the problem, if it hasn't damaged the light as well.

Comment: @dandavis The reading lamp is working fine. Manufacture told me that they doubt the problem is the power supply since the reading like is working. Anyhow, first time this thing broke I was looking for an alternative power supply and I couldn't find anything. Can you point me out to anything that could do the job and would be more reliable?

Comment: you have to match up the output voltage and find one with the amps greater than or equal to the first (really can't have too many amps). I actually prefer used ones that come with name-brand products like wifi hotspots, laptops, etc; good companies won't skimp on the quality of the supply, you get a UL rating, plenty of reserve capacity and good quality parts. The after-market replacement ones found online are typically not as good, being made to maximize profit on it's sale, rather than maximizing reliability of a more expensive product.

Comment: The original power supply is giving O/P 0.8A DC 33V. So if I find one that produces 40V and 1A will work? or it better 1A and 30V? @dandavis

Comment: you don't want 40v, too much. 30v _might_ work, probably will, but it's best to match exactly. 33v is a weird voltage, i've never seen that before. You can get adjustable power supplies, but then you need a voltmeter and some know-how that we don't assume on this stack.

Comment: @dandavis do you think 35v might work too or perhaps that is too much and I'll blow away the bulbs? I'm asking because for me looks odd that both bulbs have the same voltage, so probably there is some room to play. I really don't know why they choose 33V as power source.